# My airport extreme failed - can I access my timemachine backup that was attached to the airport?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, airport

I am still running an older macbook pro on El Capitan (10.11.6), with a timemachine backup running to an external harddrive connected to the USB port of the airport extreme.

The airport has now failed, and I want to continue using the same backup harddrive by just plugging it directly into the mbp.  However, the mbp does not recognize the previous backups, and wants to start a new backup if I select this disk in the Timemachine preferences.

I really dont want to start a full new backup, or might even want to access some of my older files - can you please help?

Thanks,

Charlie

Comment: You can access the old ones, with Migration Assistant.  You cannot re-associate the backup, a network backup is not structured the same way as a backup on a localdrive.

Comment: Thanks Marc - much appreciated! Will give it a go!